# How to set 3 languages with php?

Tags: php, internationalization

I try to insert a third language in an existing page which is already in French and English.
I'm kind of beginner with php.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$lang = (isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] == 'en') ? 'en' : 'fr' ;
$langParam = ($lang == 'en') ? '&lang=en' : '';
$typeTerms = array(


'fr' => array(
    'WINES' => 'vins',
    'BEERS' => 'Bières',
    'MALTCOOLER' => 'boisson à base de malt',
    'CIDER' => 'cidres',
    'ALCOHOLFREE' => 'produits sans alcool<br/>et à faible teneur en alcool',
    'OTHERS' => 'autres'
),

'en' => array(
    'WINES' => 'Wines',
    'BEERS' => 'Beers',
    'MALTCOOLER' => 'Malt Based Cooler',
    'CIDER' => 'Cider',
    'ALCOHOLFREE' => 'Alcohol-free and low-alcoholic products',
    'OTHERS' => 'Others'
)
);
?>
```

And I want to insert this array, and make it work!

```
'zh' => array(
    'WINES' => '葡萄酒',
    'BEERS' => '啤酒',
    'MALTCOOLER' => '麦芽果酒',
    'CIDER' => '苹果酒',
    'ALCOHOLFREE' => '无酒精及低度酒精饮料',
    'OTHERS' => '其它'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just

```
 $lang = isset($_GET['lang'])?$_GET['lang']:"en";
 if(!in_array($lang,array("en","fr","zh"))) $lang = "en";
```

To add a new one:

```
    $typeTerms['zh'] = array(
        'WINES' => '葡萄酒',
        'BEERS' => '啤酒',
        'MALTCOOLER' => '麦芽果酒',
        'CIDER' => '苹果酒',
        'ALCOHOLFREE' => '无酒精及低度酒精饮料',
        'OTHERS' => '其它'
    );
```

Comment: No his `$lang` var is currently set with an either/or. That needs to be fixed too.

Comment: @DigitalChris No, it doesn't.

Comment: The example falls back to `fr`, so the second line should be: `if(!in_array($lang,array("en","fr","zh"))) $lang = "fr";`

Comment: @Shomz sure about that? What is is $lang set for, except to be used as the key to pull the correct value from $typeTerms?

Comment: @DigitalChris i'ld say it is just a fallback. When no lang get parameter is set, it falls back to `fr`

Comment: If it's not one of the array values, if falls back to 'en' (Merguez was right, it should fall back to 'fr'). I'd go one step further and check for the real language keys from `$typeTerms` instead of an array that would have to be updated every time you update a language.

Comment: The full code is not here, but it's pretty clear that it would be used like `$typeTerms[$lang]['WINES']` so if you don't set $lang properly, it's not going to work.  @Shomz - when I made that first comment cardeol hadn't edited to add the first 2 lines.

Comment: Well..... Guys thanks a lot for your help!

But I have to admit that I am a little bit confused by now with all your answers...

I said I'm beginner with PHP, Can I just get one answer wich work properly and write it from beginning to the end please.

Thanks again!

Comment: @user3271655 check mine ;)

Comment: @silentw your code look fine and I like it cuz its complete from beginning to the end but sorry... Still work in French and English, but not in Chinese

Comment: Then there is something else not related to this piece of code.

Comment: @user3271655 If my answer helped you out, please accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: @silentw yes I accept it as the correct answer, but what do I have to do exactly? Sorry its my first time asking a question on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Using the switch statement to check if the language is either `en` or `zh`. If it's `fr` or something else, fallbacks to the main language `fr`.

```
<?php

    switch($_GET['lang']) {
        case 'en' : $lang = 'en'; break;
        case 'zh' : $lang = 'zh'; break;
        case 'fr' :
        default: $lang = 'fr'; break;
    }

    $langParam = in_array( $lang, array('en', 'zh') ) ? '&lang=' . $lang : '';

    $typeTerms = array(

        'fr' => array(
            'WINES' => 'vins',
            'BEERS' => 'Bières',
            'MALTCOOLER' => 'boisson à base de malt',
            'CIDER' => 'cidres',
            'ALCOHOLFREE' => 'produits sans alcool<br/>et à faible teneur en alcool',
            'OTHERS' => 'autres'
        ),

        'en' => array(
            'WINES' => 'Wines',
            'BEERS' => 'Beers',
            'MALTCOOLER' => 'Malt Based Cooler',
            'CIDER' => 'Cider',
            'ALCOHOLFREE' => 'Alcohol-free and low-alcoholic products',
            'OTHERS' => 'Others'
        ),

        'zh' => array(
            'WINES' => '葡萄酒',
            'BEERS' => '啤酒',
            'MALTCOOLER' => '麦芽果酒',
            'CIDER' => '苹果酒',
            'ALCOHOLFREE' => '无酒精及低度酒精饮料',
            'OTHERS' => '其它'
        )

    );

?>
```

Comment: The downvote seems gone, but your isset implementation is just horrible... so a downvote would be justified. Try adding 5 more languages and see what your code will look like.

Comment: @Shomz just followed the OP logic, I added a method using `switch` statement falling back to the default *fr*

Comment: Understood, but you just shouldn't follow that if you have more than two options, right. The switch method is perfect.

Comment: @Shomz Thanks for the fb, just updated my answer so that the `switch` statement is the only answer.

Answer (score 0):

simply check if `$_GET['lang']` is set:

```
if(isset($_GET['lang']) && in_array($_GET['lang'], array('en, 'fr', 'zh')))
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
else
    $lang = 'en'; // your Default lang
```

Then define words array:

```
$words = array(
'en' => array(...),
    'fr' => array(...),
    'zh' => array(...)
);
```

and to use array:

```
echo $words[$lang]['beers'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if it exists in your language array, and if not, fall back to `fr`:

```
$typeTerms = array(
    // terms go here
);
$lang = isset( $typeTerms[ $_GET[ 'lang' ] ] ) ? $_GET[ 'lang' ] : 'fr';
$langParam = ($lang != 'fr') ? "&lang=$lang" : '';
```

Note that you need to place this code **after** you define the `$typeTerms`.

This way, you can add as many languages to your `$typeTerms` and never have to worry about making other changes to the code.

Comment: That would only work if `$typeTerms` was defined before your line.

Comment: @silentw True, I'll add an explanation.